# Scanner skipping first input in loop Java

Tags: java, loops

This is a basic name sorting program. Everything works except for the fact that the user cannot input the first name. This is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names do you want to sort");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[num];
    for (int x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
        int pos = x+1;
        System.out.println("Enter name " + pos);
        //String temp = sc.nextLine();
        names[x] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    String sortedArray[] = sort(names);
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print(sortedArray[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Update: I changed the code so if it is the first time, it calls sc.nextLine() and then sets the input equal to names[0]
One problem with .next() is that if a person's first name is 2 words to treats it as two names. This is the updated code that works:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names do you want to sort");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[num];
    //String[] temp = new String[names.length];
    for (int x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
        int pos = x + 1;
        if (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter name 1");
            sc.nextLine();
            names[0] = sc.nextLine();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter name " + pos);
            //String temp = sc.nextLine();
            names[x] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
    String sortedArray[] = sort(names);
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(sortedArray[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sc.next();` instead of `sc.nextLine();`

- `next()` will find and return the next complete token from the input stream.
- `nextLine()` will advance the scanner past the current line and will return the input that was skipped

Also, check below description from `Scanner#nextLine()`.

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names do you want to sort");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    String[] names = new String[num];
    for (int x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
        int pos = x+1;
        System.out.println("Enter name " + pos);
        //String temp = sc.nextLine();
        names[x] = sc.next();
    }
    /*String sortedArray[] = sort(names);
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print(sortedArray[i] + " ");
    }*/
```

Comment: Have you got your answer, if not then please write your answer so that other's can be benefited from it. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer